# Thymeleaf text and html version

Tags: email, spring-boot, html-email, thymeleaf, velocity

Is there any way we can send both text and html version in same sampletemplate.html file? We have been using Java Mail Sender API to create both plain text content and html content. We have tried the below code:
Your name is [[${TestName}]] to display text version but it's not mapping the values since it doesn't recognize the format.
Did try below version as well

```
[# th:if="${PLAIN}"]
    Your name is [[${TestName}]]
[/]
[# th:if="${PLAIN} = false"]
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
     xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" >
     <head></head><body>Your name is [[${TestName}]]</body</html>
```

Is there any way I can have both the text and html version in my template.I am using Spring boot but trying to remove existing velocity template as they are not supported anymore. Any other template engine that help me achieve this? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `template engine` configuring it as `txt` resolver, like next:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ThymeleafConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    private TemplateEngine templateEngine(ITemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver txtViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine(txtTemplateResolver()));
        resolver.setContentType("text/plain");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF8);
        resolver.setViewNames(array("*.html"));
        return resolver;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver txtTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Then you would parse all as text, avoiding HTML template resolver errors, so you use a boolean like you have done and parse the txt or html:

```
[# th:if="${PLAIN} = true"]
    Your name is [# th:utext="${TestName}" /]
[/]
[# th:if="${PLAIN} = false"]
    <html lang="en">
     <head></head><body>Your name is [# th:utext="${TestName}" /]</body</html>
[/]
```

Then you just add the generated txt by thymeleaf to your mail.

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you so much!! Got couple of follow up questions though-
The template will be .html or .txt file? It still will need declaration that its thymeleaf template
      <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> Won't that create a issue?
Do you have any idea how can I test text version of sending email in outlook or gmail?

Comment: The template must be what you set in  `resolver.setViewNames(array("*.html"));`. In the example is html but you can use what you want. Otherwise you are right, delete thymeleaf declaration `xmlns:th="thymeleaf.org"`, I did not realize (answer updated)

Comment: Otherwise to test version text, I guess you are using Spring MimeMessageHelper class, so just use it methods: `setText(String text, boolean html)` and set the boolean html to false or true, depend you want to be html or not

Comment: Thanks again @Pau.. I got that figured out. There is so much to learn about Thymeleaf that I have yet to explore.